# Requested Json parse failed from a php file

Tags: php, ajax, json, parsing

I am trying to make an application for LG Smart TV. In index.html, trying to get an json from a website.

This is how i call the json located in my website:
(note that it is called test.php in LG ide)

```
 <?php
header("Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8");
echo get_url("http://website.com/proxy/collection.php?format=json&main_category_id=2");
function get_url($request_url){
$ch=curl_init($request_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $request_url);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 10);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
return $response;
}
?>
```

and in index.html, the code below trying to parse json using ajax:

```
$.ajax({ 
type:"get"
,dataType: 'json' 
,url: 'test.php'
,success: function(jsonData){
//things to do

}
});
```

The other thing is that when i try to run this code in localhost using xampp there is no problem, i mean the code perfectly works but when it comes to compiling in LG IDE I am getting  requested JSON parse error. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

This are the things which are wrong with your code:

- You are missing a `;` in line 2
- Your function should get the called name, that should look like this: `function get_url($url) { ...`
- You have to give a url to the curl_init with `curl_init($url)`
- In the line with the return you wrote `response`, it has to be `$response`
- When you are returning a json you should set the header as well with `header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");`

I hope thats all. You could post the errors as well to get better support. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php) how to show them.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Those are miswritten (missing ; and $). I ve edited them.Also added the header in php file but nothing changed.Thanks again.

Comment: can you show me the new code? where have you added the header, have you changed the function as well? is error reporting turned on?

Comment: Just edited my post. Interestingly it works on localhost but does not work on smart tv emulator which works as virtual machine in virtualbox.Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: propably because the virtual machine has no internet access